# Using tSQLt AssertEqualsTableSchema in a test procedure that contains TRY/CATCH

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsqlt

It seems that the SQL test framework tSQLt does not allow to use an assertion such as tSQLt.AssertEqualsTableSchema after a TRY/CATCH block that generates an error. If I try that, the test generates an error instead of a pass/fail result. On the other hand, a simpler assertion such as  tSQLt.AssertEquals works in such a case, passing the test.

I would like to know if there is a way to use such assert satements in this case, or if it is a fundamental limitation of tSQLt and it does not work.

This code reproduces the problem:

```
EXEC tSQLt.NewTestClass @ClassName = N'errtest';
GO

CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE errtest.test_simple
AS
BEGIN
    
    PRINT('Executing errtest.test_simple');

    CREATE TABLE Actual (
        A INT,
        B NVARCHAR(10));

    CREATE TABLE Expected (
        A INT,
        B NVARCHAR(10));

    BEGIN TRY
        DECLARE @IntegerVariable AS INT;
        SET @IntegerVariable = 'a string';
        PRINT('There were no errors.');
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        PRINT('An error happened.');
    END CATCH

    DECLARE @AssertType NVARCHAR(100);
    SET @AssertType = 'AssertAssertEqualsTableSchema';
    --SET @AssertType = 'AssertEquals';

    IF @AssertType = 'AssertEquals' BEGIN
        PRINT('ASSERT: Equals for 2 INTs');
        EXEC tSQLt.AssertEquals @Expected = 1
                               ,@Actual = 1
                               ,@Message = N'no'
    END 
    ELSE BEGIN
        PRINT('ASSERT: EqualsTableSchema');
        EXEC tSQLt.AssertEqualsTableSchema @Expected = N'Expected'
                                          ,@Actual = N'Actual'
                                          ,@Message = N'Hallo'
    END

END
GO


EXEC tSQLt.Run 'errtest.test_simple';
```

If this is run with tSQLt installed, I get following result:

```
Executing errtest.test_simple
An error happened.
ASSERT: EqualsTableSchema
[errtest].[test_simple] failed: (Error) The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot support operations that write to the log file. Roll back the transaction.[16,1]{tSQLt.AssertEqualsTableSchema,7} (There was also a ROLLBACK ERROR --> The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot be rolled back to a savepoint. Roll back the entire transaction.{tSQLt.Private_RunTest,187})
 
+----------------------+
|Test Execution Summary|
+----------------------+
 
|No|Test Case Name         |Dur(ms)|Result|
+--+-----------------------+-------+------+
|1 |[errtest].[test_simple]|      3|Error |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Msg 50000, Level 16, State 10, Line 47
Test Case Summary: 1 test case(s) executed, 0 succeeded, 0 skipped, 0 failed, 1 errored.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

However, if I uncomment the line `--SET @AssertType = 'AssertEquals';`, the simpler assertion tSQLt.AssertEquals runs without errors and passes the test:

```
Executing errtest.test_simple
An error happened.
ASSERT: Equals for 2 INTs
 
+----------------------+
|Test Execution Summary|
+----------------------+
 
|No|Test Case Name         |Dur(ms)|Result |
+--+-----------------------+-------+-------+
|1 |[errtest].[test_simple]|      7|Success|
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test Case Summary: 1 test case(s) executed, 1 succeeded, 0 skipped, 0 failed, 0 errored.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here is a list of which assertion works and which do not work in the above example.

Working: AssertEquals, AssertEqualsString, AssertNotEquals, AssertObjectDoesNotExist, AssertObjectExists, Fail, (no assert used) → test passes

Not working:
AssertEqualsTableSchema, AssertEmptyTable, AssertEqualsTable, AssertLike, AssertResultSetsHaveSameMetaData

Comment: https://github.com/tSQLt-org/tSQLt/blob/main/Tests/AssertEqualsTableSchemaTests.class.sql

Comment: @lptr could you elaborate on your point? I am not sure what you are getting at

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that tSQLt starts a transaction - this is needed so faking objects can be rolled back and any helper objects it creates are removed. But errors in try catch can doom the transaction. `tSQLt.AssertEqualsTableSchema` attempts to insert to tables `tSQLt.Private_AssertEqualsTableSchema_Expected` and `tSQLt.Private_AssertEqualsTableSchema_Actual` which would write to the log file hence the error.

As a workaround you can do your own check in a manner that does not touch the transaction log. Example below (based on the `SELECT` that tSQLt does)

```
  IF EXISTS (SELECT *
             FROM   (
                      SELECT 
                          C.object_id,
                          RANK()OVER(PARTITION BY C.object_id ORDER BY C.column_id) AS col_ordinal,
                          C.name,
                          CAST(C.system_type_id AS NVARCHAR(MAX))+QUOTENAME(TS.name) system_type_id,
                          CAST(C.user_type_id AS NVARCHAR(MAX))+CASE WHEN TU.system_type_id<> TU.user_type_id THEN QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(TU.schema_id))+'.' ELSE '' END + QUOTENAME(TU.name) user_type_id,
                          C.max_length,
                          C.precision,
                          C.scale,
                          C.collation_name,
                          C.is_nullable
                        FROM sys.columns AS C
                        JOIN sys.types AS TS
                          ON C.system_type_id = TS.user_type_id
                        JOIN sys.types AS TU
                          ON C.user_type_id = TU.user_type_id
                       WHERE C.object_id IN ( OBJECT_ID('dbo.Expected'), OBJECT_ID('dbo.Actual'))
                     ) T
                     GROUP BY col_ordinal, name, system_type_id, user_type_id, max_length, precision, scale, collation_name, is_nullable
                     HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
             )
  EXEC [tSQLt].Fail 'Unexpected/missing column(s)'
```

Obviously the above could be made more elaborate to return more details of specific differences and itself be moved into a stored proc to facilitate re-use.